# Почему в данном коде img смотрит на z-index самого верхнего предка вместо прямого и то при условий того, что у него стоит position: relative?

Tags: html, css

Чтобы поместить картинку позади относительно его прямого родителя приходится работать с z-index и указывать еще один position: relative для самого верхнего предка. Как бы я не старался, но дочерний элемент `img` плевать хотел, что я указываю его родителю, он смотрит на другого предка.
 И еще интересней, он тоже плевать хотел на верхнего предка, если у него не стоит `position: relative`, как так это вообще работает?
В данном примере я показываю результат работы, который ожидается.
По логике изначально я указал z-index элементу `.block` и элементу `img` на 1-н уровень меньше, но это не работает, а так же если убрать `position: relative` у элемента `.center`, то тоже все перестанет работать.
Я понимаю, что если убрать эту доп.обертку `center`, то все будет работать как и задумывалось, но меня больше интересует данный случай.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.center {
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="block">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задать контекст наложения прямому родителю, то обойти его прямому ребенку не будет возможности. Иначе говоря, прямой ребенок не может обойти своего родителя по оси z назад, если прямой родитель имеет свой контекст наложения - родитель всегда будет позади ребенка. Так что этого можно избежать манипулируя уровнями вложения элементов.

```css
.first,
.second,
.third {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.first {
    background: green;
    z-index:999;
}
.second {
    background: yellow;
    left:40px;
    z-index: 500;
}
.third {
    background: red;
    left:80px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```